# How private is indexeddb data?

Tags: security, indexeddb

I'm just starting with indexeddb to replace the local storage implementation I had. With local storage, I know that the stored data is unique to the domain, iframes and the user account running it. But now in indexxed db, is it the same thing? As in if I were to visit a page from another domain or change user, would it have it's own indexeddb data?

Comment: IndexedDB storage implementations are required to follow the [same-origin policy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) in exactly the same way that Local Storage does.

Comment: What about different user accounts?

Comment: The IndexedDB behavior with respect to user accounts is also exactly the same as with Local Storage.

Answer (score 4):

IndexedDB and localStorage has exactly the same privacy/security policies. I.e. they both ensure that the data is isolated on a per-origin basis. Where "origin" means scheme+domain+port.

So "http://website.com", "http://otherwebsite.com", "http://other.website.com", "https://website.com" and "http://website.com:8080" all are isolated from each other and can't open each other's localStorage or IndexedDB databases.

This is true in all browsers.

Comment: Not exactly the same! you can access to indexedDB from the service worker but local storage is available there...